# how to retrieve all data from a particular document in couch db?

Tags: gwt, couchdb

I have a document where i am saving all the user registration information with a particular random id associated to it.
my document looks like:

_id:xyz
_rev:9-a4d476aa9f4b41879d21a7f475a2f1d5

-742566755

```
       course:gg

       passwdt:t

       phone:1313

       clgnme:hfhjf

       address:fjhfj
```

-884381686

```
       course:gg

       passwdt:t

       phone:1313

       clgnme:hfhjf

       address:fjhfj
```

Now, i Want to retrieve the document with all information as shown in the document.
I want that it should be shown individually as i have done with getting the values on console. but i want it acording to each id individually.

Like if i want to get data of -884381686 id and it can be anything name, address anything. it should fetch data accordingly.
**NOTE:**PROGRAMMING TO BE DONE IN GWT

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to access each document via its ID? You can just make an HTTP GET request to (assuming CouchDb is run locally):

```
GET localhost:5984/<database>/<id>
```

That will return the entire document

Based on your comment below, the best way to get each item in the document is to create a map view in Couch. Say your document looks like this:

```
{
_id: 123,
rev: 22,
posts: [{ id: 2, name: hello}, {id: 3, name: world}]
}
```

If you wanted to list all of the posts, your Map view would look like this:

```
function(doc){
  for(var post in doc.posts){
    emit([doc._id, post], 1);
  }
}
```

That will emit all of the posts in every single document. If you have different types of documents, you can add code to only emit for certain types of documents. Then you can go to the URL for the view to see all of the posts: `http://localhost:5984/database/_design/ViewCategory/_view/ViewName?reduce=false`

Comment: I am able to get the whole document but i want individual data according to a particular field..

Comment: i have to read about views , new to couchdb.. Still a big thanks for ur help. hope i get through my problem soon